# What photo characteristics work best with facial recognition software?

Tags: software, image-processing, features, face-detection, computational-photography

I have teams that are doing surveys and taking photos of respondents (in and around their homes, often outside) with permission to take and use these photos for facial recognition. We're complying with a wide range of privacy laws, disclosures, etc.

Now, I have to give these teams instructions for what photos will work best with facial recognition tools. What would the best set of instructions be?

Thus far I have:

- Take photos straight on (rather than at an angle)
- Avoid shadows across faces
- Ensure there are no other people in the picture
- Ensure there are no pictures or other 'faces' in the background
- Edited to add: - [Ensure face is sufficiently large within picture](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11042-013-1568-8) ([example image](https://static-content.springer.com/image/art%3A10.1007%2Fs11042-013-1568-8/MediaObjects/11042_2013_1568_Fig1_HTML.gif))

Anything else you'd recommend? Are these instructions good? Does filesize / resolution tend to matter a lot? What about lighting? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will totally depend on what facial recognition software you are using. A few other things to suggest are:

- Make sure there is no **occlusion** of the subjects face in an image (such as wearing sunglasses, the subject having hair over their face etc)
- Ensure the subjects **eyes** are in focus (many facial recognition algorithms rely on the eyes being important features for detection)
- Ensure the photo is at a correct **exposure**.

Comment: Great, thanks. We're currently using dlib, but we may change in the future, so general tips like above are best.

These will be taken by minimally trained people on mobile android phones / tablets... is there any tips specific to that? With regard to exposure, would a 'HDR' setting help ensure that?

Comment: An HDR image with people is not generally a good idea as HDR images are created by combining multiple exposures and people move a lot more than you think between exposures. It's not impossible to do, but you're probably less likely to get a good one for your purposes with HDR.

Comment: How would you best instruct those using mobile phones to have a correct exposure? Tapping the face of the person in the photo?